# Como suprimir a janela de input do Oracle sem usar set define off

Tags: php, imagem, oracle, set

Preciso inserir uma imagem no oracle usando php, porem depois que converto ela para inserir no banco, ela recebe alguns caracteres & no meio da string, esse caractere no Oracle dispara uma tela de input, quando é disparada essa tela de input, o php se perde e lança uma exceção, ja tentei usar set define off para suprimir a tela de input porém sem sucesso, meu usuario do oracle não tem essa permissão e não tem como eu conseguir outro usuario, qual seria o meio de contornar essa questão? a pergunta seria, como suprimir a tela de input do oracle sem usar o set define off.

Essa é a tela de input que preciso suprimir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: teria como postar seu código php que esta usando para inserir ?

Comment: O problema não está no insert e sim em sumprimir a tela de input sem usar o set define off, se eu postar o insert vou acabar tirando o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Eu também acho estranha a questão, eu também gostaria de ver como esta sendo executada essa linha.

Comment: Faça um teste, tente inserir em uma coluna com o tipo `varchar2(10)` em uma tabela de teste,  com o valor: `R0b&rT0` e verifique se esta inserindo. Usando PHP, claro.

Comment: Ja fiz esse teste David quando tento fazer isso o Oracle dispara a janela de input que está no print ali em cima, foi assim que descobri o erro depois de muitas tentativas, quando o php se depara com essa janela ele dispara uma exceção eu tempo de execução seria quase impossivel eu fazer o php se comunicar com essa janela em background, preciso desabilitar esse input sem usar usar o set define off

Comment: Não manjo tanto de PHP, mas acredito muito que o problema esta no seu código PHP, esta usando PDO? mysqli? Poste seu código, acredito que alguém consiga ajudar.

Comment: Você pode usar set escape?

Comment: Não posso usar set, infelizmente.

Comment: Então, estou usando PDO sim, se fosse pra melhorar teria que ser a parte do código que transforma a foto em hexadecimal, só pq precisaria mudar o sistema inteiro, então se eu conseguisse resolver dessa maneira seria ótimo.

Comment: Pode usar outro caracter diferente de &?

Comment: Posso, só pq como esse caractere está no meio de uma foto trasnformada em hexadecimal, cada string dessa tem uns 6000 caracteres é inviavel a cada nova foto fazer a procura manual desses caracteres dentro da string.

Comment: @ROBERTOALBINOJUNIOR, Acredito que o seu problema esteja especificamente na query que faz o insert. Isto me parece um erro simples de escape de string. Normalmente o PDO escapa tudo quando utiliza PreparedStatement. Você está concatenando a query ou utilizando PreparedStatements ?

Comment: Concatenando a query

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ESCAPE '\'   

CREATE TABLE TABELA ( 
   C1 VARCHAR(10),
   C2 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO TABELA VALUES ( 'CAR\&LOS', 'ANDOR\&INHA')
```

Comment: Não posso usar SET.